# Which is the best data loader for Salesforce?

Tags: data-loader, bestpractice

Over time, I have come across three data loaders for Salesforce...

- Apex Data Loader,
- Jitterbit Data Loader, and
- dataloader.io

to name a few.

---

1. Are there any more data loaders for Salesforce?
2. Which is your favourite data loader and why?
3. If you had the choice of mastering only one data loader, which one would you prefer to master, and why?

Comment: No need to master anything, Enabler4Excel can be used by a 5-year-old:
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B3GBzEAN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is pretty general and will probably get closed because of that.

For what purpose would you be choosing a data loader?  The simple [Import Wizard](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/import_wizards.htm) works fine for many situations.

I would recommend using the right tool for the specific job which might be a different tool depending on the situation.  Don't choose the tool before the job.  See [Which Data Import/Export Tool Should I Use?](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/import_which_data_import_tool.htm) for some general information.

Answer (score 4):

http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/Jitterbit-Data-Loader-for-Salesforce-vs-Apex-Data-Loader/td-p/500231

Jitter bit dataloader seems more powerful among all.The reviews are great on appexchange .This tool can also be used to automate the data migration process from legacy system .The bulk API is used behind this tool and hence looks good choice since we have flexibility of changing the Batch Sizes.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use the Excel Connector far more often (I'm Admin/Low Level Developer - I would personally NOT TRUST average users to use the Connector).  Otherwise, I just use DataLoader.  The ability to instantly both query AND update data from and to SF is just too awesome.

https://code.google.com/p/excel-connector/w/list

Edit (to answer your third question):

Excel Connector is worth mastering.  You can do FAR MORE with it in my opinion since, quite simply, it's Excel and VBA and whatever you can dream up.  I am NOT proficient in the .io or the other product.  I can't imagine them having the extensibility of Excel, though.